# Syntax Error when using .loc on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-error

Given the following pandas DataFrame -

| **json_path** | **Reporting Group** | **Entity/Grouping** | **Entity ID** | **Adjusted Value (Today, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)** | **Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)** | **Adjusted Value (No Div, USD)** | **TWR Audit Note** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0] | Barrack Family | William and Rupert Trust | 9957007 | -1.44 |  |  |  | -1.44 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[0].children.[0] | Barrack Family | Cash | - | -1.44 |  |  |  | -1.44 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1] | Barrack Family | Gratia Holdings No. 2 LLC | 8413655 | 55491732.66 | -0.971018847 | -0.971018847 | 11.52490309 | 55491732.66 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1].children.[0] | Barrack Family | Investment Grade Fixed Income | - | 18469768.6 |  |  |  | 18469768.6 |  |
| data.attributes.total.children.[0].children.[0].children.[1].children.[1] | Barrack Family | High Yield Fixed Income | - | 3668982.44 | -0.205356545 | -0.205356545 | 4.441190127 | 3668982.44 |  |

The following code should filter out rows where rows != 'Cash' (`Entity/Grouping` column) and that have a blank value in either `Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)` column, `Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)` column or `Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)` column.

**Code:** The following code expects to achieve this -

```
def twr_exceptions_logic():
    perf_asset_class_df = databases_creation()

    m1 = perf_asset_class_df.loc[(perf_asset_class_df['Entity/Grouping']!= 'Cash')
    m2 = perf_asset_class_df[['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)',
                              'Adjusted TWR (YTD, No Div, USD)',
                              'Annualized Adjusted TWR (Since Inception, No Div, USD)']].eq('').any(1))
    perf_asset_class_df.loc[m1&m2]
    
    return perf_asset_class_df
```

**Issue:** I seem to be getting the following `SyntaxError` and cannot triangulate what's wrong with the given code -

```
  File "C:\Users\WILLIA~1.FOR\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18756/2073129889.py", line 11
    m2 = perf_asset_class_df[['Adjusted TWR (Current Quarter, No Div, USD)',
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any hints would be warmly received?

Comment: You're missing a `]` on the previous line.

Comment: Well that takes embarrassment to a new level. Thank you, and I'll be more diligent next time!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Barmar for pointing out that I had a missing `]`. Correct syntax as follows for `m1` -

`m1 = perf_asset_class_df.loc[(perf_asset_class_df['Entity/Grouping']!= 'Cash')]`